# Matrix similarity proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices

I need to show that the matrices

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}  
$$                 and $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}  
$$

aren't similar. I tried with trace, determinant, eigenvalues, rank space but their all the same.

Can someone help?

Comment: Are they invertible considering that $\det A=\det B=0$?

Comment: No they're not cause determinant is equal to zero.

Comment: Is that also a criteria for similarity? I don't imagine that it was mentioned in my lecture

Comment: There's a row all zero.

Comment: In fact you won't be able to show they are not similar.  They are similar.

Comment: So the exercise is wrong here?

Comment: The two matrices above are definitely similar, i.e. $A = S^{-1}BS$ for suitable invertible matrix $S$.

Comment: I remember that two matrix $A,  B\in\Bbb K_n$  are '''similar''' if there exists an invertible matrix $C$ such that $B = C^{-1} A C$.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! This thing literally teared the arse out of me!

Comment: @hardmath I remembered it well. :-)

Answer (score 4):

That will be hard, since they *are* similar:$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}.\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I think it should be the other way arounf with $P^{-1}$ and $P$, although here the difference doesn't shown because $P^{-1}=P$.

Answer (score 2):

The "softest" way to see they're similar: Being upper triangular, they both have eigenvalues $0$ and $1$. Hence, being $2\times 2$, they're both diagonalizable, and with the same diagonal matrix.